# Error in retrieving notification_key for group messaging in FCM

Tags: android, firebase, rest, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I was able to create a `notification_key` from `notification_key_name` as mentioned in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#creating_a_device_group).

However, when I went to retrieving the `notification_key` from `notification_key_name` using

[image]

I get the error:

> Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a silly mistake (thanks to docs as always), the request `body` should **NOT** be `{}` but empty.

[image]